# Unable to range facet on field:DateRangeValue type=date_range

Tags: json, date, solr, range

I have a query to Solr

```
     JObject finalQuery = new JObject
        {
            new JProperty("query", "*:*")
        };
                    JObject jFacet = JObject.Parse(@"   {
                                              ""Buckets"" : {
                                                ""type"": ""range"",
                                                ""field"" : ""DateTimeValue"",
                                                ""start"" : ""NOW/YEAR-11YEAR"",
                                                ""end"" : ""NOW"",
                                                ""gap"" : ""+1YEAR""
                                                }
                                            }          
                                        ");

        finalQuery.Add(new JProperty("facet", jFacet));
        IRestResponse response = ExecuteRetriveQueryOnParticularCollection(finalQuery, solrUrl);
        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

it is OK . but when I replace DateTimeValue to DateRangeValue give me an error like this
"Unable to range facet on field:DateRangeValue type=date_range"

Comment: As a DateRangeValue is expanded to multiple values under the hood it's not really suitable for faceting. What do you want to achieve by faceting on that value, and not the DateTimeValue? Are you looking for how many documents that match within each interval, even if they just span the interval and doesn't have a start/end date inside the interval itself?

Comment: I have some data like this
 
 {
            "id":"497942959",
            "Name":"oliver",
            "Title":"trip",
     "DateRangeValue":"2016-01-05T00:00:00.000Z TO 2018-12-06T00:00:00.000Z"
 },
 {
            "id":"497942960",
            "Name":"jasper",
            "Title":"trip",
     "DateRangeValue":"2017-12-05T00:00:00.000Z TO 2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
 }
 
    and I want
 "How many trips are made each year" from these data

Comment: So in your case the answer would be 2, right? Since both overlap 2018?

Comment: the result is {"2010-01-01T00:00:00Z",0,
"2011-01-01T00:00:00Z",0,
"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",0, 
"2013-01-01T00:00:00Z",0,
"2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",0,
"2015-01-01T00:00:00Z",0,
"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",1,
"2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",2,
"2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",2,
"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",1}

Comment: Isn't that the correct result from what you're asking? There are two trips that span 2017 and two that span 2018, one for 2016 and one for 2019? .. or is that your example of the result you want?

Comment: yes I want the result which I said from the data